# Signal safety of __sync_fetch_and_add()

Tags: c, multithreading, signals, atomic

I have a program that accepts socket clients and forks a child process. To keep the count of the child processes, I am using a global variable and atomic functions are used for incrementing and decrementing the count.

I am concerned about the signal safety of __sync_fetch_and_add(). Is there a possibility of deadlock when the multiple childs are connecting and disconnecting frequently.

Below is a snippet of my code.

```
   int main()
   {
            ...
            signal(SIGCHLD, handle_sigchild);
            ...
            if ((pid = fork()) == -1) {
                close(sock);
                continue;
            } else if (pid > 0) { //Parent
                __sync_fetch_and_add(&counter, 1);
                close(sock);
                continue;
            } else if (pid == 0) {
            ...
            }
        ...
    }
    
    // Signal Handler
    void handle_sigchild(int arg)
    {
        while( waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG) > 0){
            __sync_fetch_and_add(&counter, -1);
        }
        signal(SIGCHLD, handle_sigchild);
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong with a simple [`sig_atomic_t`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.14)?

Comment: @Frank Thanks. I will edit the tags

Comment: Are you stuck with using a very old version of gcc? Using `__sync_fetch_and_add` instead of `__atomic_add_fetch` nowadays is a bit suspicious.

Comment: I'm also puzzled by the question being about "deadlock". There's a few things that can go wrong with atomic operations, but deadlocks are not one of them *by definition* (logic errors within your own code notwithstanding)

Comment: Currently I'm seeing some random freezes during the operation. I'm investigating the reason for that. Therefore I suspected some kind of deadlock. The issue being rare cannot be debugged easily.

Comment: It is also unclear why atomic variable is used in the context. From what I can see, the code is single-threaded and `counter` is not shared between threads or processes. It probably needs to be `volatile`, not atomic.

Comment: @SergeyA [Not really](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.14.1.1p5): "If the signal occurs other than as the result of calling the abort or raise function, **the behavior is undefined** if the signal handler refers to any object with static or thread storage duration that is not a lock-free atomic object other than by assigning a value to an object declared as `volatile sig_atomic_t` ..."

Comment: @AndrewHenle true, it has to be `volatile sig_atomic_t` - but specific atomic routines are still not needed.

Comment: Deadlocks cannot happen. Livelocks can happen, but are seldom and usually resolve themselves when one of the involved processors takes an interrupt.

Comment: I believe you need to restore the signal handler before collecting all child processes, otherwise you have a race condition where it is possible that a SIGCHLD is delivered after the last wait, but before the handler is reinstated, and that goes into the default handler. That wouldn't explain *frequent* deadlocks though, because the next child process exiting would fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Atomic functions are typically implemented as a loop around a critical instruction that performs the actual operation, and that can fail in which case it needs to be retried.

Any conflict would cause the critical instruction to fail, and that also goes for conflicts introduced by signal handlers.

For example, [*fetch-and-add*](https://godbolt.org/z/qKhcrWEsY) is typically something like

```
.L2:
    lwarx 10,0,3
    addi 9,10,1
    stwcx. 9,0,3
    bne 0,.L2
    extsw 3,10
    blr
```

So the value is loaded and a reservation made, then incremented, then stored back if the reservation is still valid. If that failed, we restart with fetching the new value (since it is likely that someone wrote in the meantime).

On Intel, this process is hidden inside

```
    mov     eax, 1
    lock xadd       DWORD PTR [rdi], eax
    ret
```

On old machines, this would indeed have locked the entire bus for the duration of the add instruction, on newer, it silently generates a loop in microcode that repeatedly tries to increment the value.

Any interrupt (which would be necessary to deliver a signal) would just extend the time between load and store, which makes it more likely that the current iteration fails to update the value because something else was faster.